# Using global variables in a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a C++ DLL with 3 classes in it. I added a static boolean variable to my "stdafx" header file (since all of my classes include it) and am trying to use it. While all of my classes see my variable, they each seem to have a different instance of it. If I set the variable to true in once class then I'll notice that it's false in another class. Is there any way that I can create a variable that can be used across all classes only within the DLL?

Comment: Isn't `stdafx` your MSVS precompiled headers support? Should you perhaps _not_ be modifying it?

Comment: I'm open to any ideas to help solve this issue. This made the most sense to me so I went with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you labelled it `static`, so that's what happens. Instead, label it `extern` in headers and define it in *one* TU.

And don't modify `stdafx`; it's not yours. Use your own shared headers.

Comment: You are allowed to modify `stdafx.h`. The auto-generated comment in the file says so *//stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files, or project specific include files that are used frequently, but are changed infrequently*

Comment: @Praetorian: But it seems like a _really_ bad idea. Mostly because it's auto-generated by the IDE; your `bool` will get lost at some point.

Comment: It is auto-generated, but only once when you create the project, and not modified by the IDE after that. I don't think it is possible to create your own precompiled header that can be used in conjunction with stdafx.h so it might just be the only option.

Comment: It does not get regenerated, ever. So no risk of losing anything you put there. On the other hand, I *would not* put any code or interfaces in it, only headers for precompilation.

Comment: I'll create a shared header file used by all classes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is `static` and you're declaring it in `stdafx.h` which is included by all source files in your project. This means each translation unit will contain its own copy of the variable, which is exactly the behavior you're seeing.

To solve this problem, declare the variable in `stdafx.cpp`

```
bool MyBool = false;
```

Then `extern` it in `stdafx.h`

```
extern bool MyBool;
```